# How can I create a Multimap in Java on Android

Tags: java, android, multimap

Where can I find an implementation of multimap for Java that will work on Android without having to include any other classes etc. The implementations I've found all require other things which require other things and it gets messy quick. I'm porting a project from C++ and am new to java (and this project as well so I'm trying to keep things as identical as possible while getting it working) so any references or examples would be great.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a Map and a List to create a multimap. Say you wanted to associate an integer with a list of class type T. Use the following code:

`Map<Integer, List<T>> myMultiMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<T>>();`

It could get messy but, this should give you what you're looking for.

Another option is to use the [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library's [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) implementations.

Comment: I was looking at Guava, but it's multimap implementation looks like it requires some other classes, which in turn require others... I don't want to install and include a pile of new stuff, I just want a simple multimap that will behave like it does in C++ to simplify the porting. Thank you for the suggestions though, should I fail to find something clean enough I may implement a map/list as you recommend, but then I have to create some management of that structure...

Comment: List in a map turned out to be the best solution for my needs.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are looking for [Apache Commons Collection](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) library. There you have a [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/index.html) class. I haven't tested it myself yet so I can't promise it works but it just looks about right for your project.

You won't find a MultiMap function in Java hence others have written libraries containing it. You can however try to implement it yourself if you're knowledge-level is high enough but that'd require some Java experience. So your best bet is to try to learn how to use and if necessary adapt libraries for using them on Android.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about code size, we just added multimaps to our utility library:
http://greenrobot.org/2015/12/11/multimaps-in-greenrobot-common-2-2/

The jar is way below 100k, which is nice if you consider Android's 65K method limit.