# Which collection should I use to store one key and three values in java?

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to store one name and corresponding left,right,top,bottom dimensions of particular view .I tried with hashmap its storing only (key, value). Please someone tell me which Collection should i use to fulfill my requirement.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFaceDetected; i++) {
    android.media.FaceDetector.Face face = myFace[i];
    Log.i("FACE","FACE TAGGING   : "+myFace[i].toString());
    String facename = myFace[i].toString();
    PointF myMidPoint = new PointF();
    face.getMidPoint(myMidPoint);
    myEyesDistance = face.eyesDistance();
    dx = (int) (myMidPoint.x - myEyesDistance);
    dy = (int) (myMidPoint.y - myEyesDistance);
    dz = (int) (myMidPoint.x + myEyesDistance);
    dt = (int) (myMidPoint.y + myEyesDistance);
    //here i want to store facename,dx,dy,dz,dt values in  same  collection
    canvas.drawRect((int) dx, dy, dz, dt, myPaint);
}
```

Comment: This link may help you too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109167/how-can-i-create-a-multimap-in-java-on-android

Apart from using a Bean class, Multimaps can also be used.

Comment: @Naveen: a Multimap is (conceptually) a `Map<K,Set<V>>`. That would not match the requirement, which is closer to `Map<K,List<V>>` (but even that would be wrong; the answer by Anders demonstrates the correct approach).

Comment: @joachim sauer: i totally agree with you.... I shared it for giving related information... Thus, provided in comment...  :)

Answer (score 5):

How about a `Map<YourKeyClass, YourValuesClass>`?

Eg.

```
class YourValuesClass
{
    int dx, dy, dz, dt;

    // getters and setters
    // ...
}

Map<String,YourValueClass> map = new HashMap<String,YourValueClass>();
```

Cheers,

Comment: +1 - exactly.  The OP is not thinking in terms of objects to a sufficient degree.

Comment: +1: another case of an OP in [object denial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3725728/40342).

Answer (score 1):

i prefer making an object representing the dimensions (three values)
and use hashmap key=facename value=faceDimension (your object)
in order to fullfill the concept of object oriented programming ;)

```
public class FaceDimension {
    private int dx;
    private int dy;
    private int dz;
    private int dt;

    public FaceDimension(int dx, int dy, int dz, int dt) {
        super();
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
        this.dz = dz;
        this.dt = dt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using a `HashMap` would be your best bet.

Comment: OP already tried using a HashMap. Telling him **how** to use it would be a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), but as you have 4 values corresponding to a key(faceName).
Create a Data Transfer Object (`DTO`) with having four properties to carry the data and put them to the map such as `hashMap.put("myface",myDto);`

For example,

```
class Position
{
    private int left;
    private int right;
    private int top;
    private int bottom;
    public int getLeft() {
        return left;
    }
    public void setLeft(int left) {
        this.left = left;
    }
    public int getRight() {
        return right;
    }
    public void setRight(int right) {
        this.right = right;
    }
    public int getTop() {
        return top;
    }
    public void setTop(int top) {
        this.top = top;
    }
    public int getBottom() {
        return bottom;
    }
    public void setBottom(int bottom) {
        this.bottom = bottom;
    }


}
```

`Map<String, Position>` faceMap = `new HashMap<String, Position>();`

Inside your for loop,

```
Position facePosition = new Position();

facePosition.setLeft(((int) (myMidPoint.x - myEyesDistance)));
```

set all the properties
then `faceMap.put("myface",facePosition);`

Comment: Making `Position` immutable (remove setters, make fields `final`, set values in constructor) would could the lines of code in half (roughly) *and* improve the readability (since you can be sure that a `Position` object never changes "right under you").

Comment: But at the time of retrieving the data ,how we can get the key(face name) ,and value(corresponding left,right,top,bottom positions)? :(

Comment: call the hashMap.get("faceKey"), it will return you the value which you putted.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried with hashmap its storing only (key, value)

Yeah, but that `value` can be of any type right?? So, use a `List` as a value in your `HashMap`.. So, you can store multiple values..

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> mapping = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
```

I have **assumed** type of `key` to be `Integer` and type of values to `String`.. You can use appropriate type..

**Or if you have `4-fixed` values, that I just saw you have**.. You can create your `Custom Type`.. just have a class containing all those values, and use **`HashMap<Integer, YourCustomClass>`**

```
public class MyDimension {
    private int top; 
    private int bottom;
    private int right;
    private int left;

    // Your Constructor

    // Use only getters, to make the object immutable..
}
```

Now, use a **`HashMap<Integer, MyDimension>`** with your `MyDimension` object storing all the 4 values..